# passing a php array to javascript array

Tags: php, javascript, mysqli

I have created a table(test) in database.
now i have fetched array in php like this.

```
 $sql="SELECT * FROM test;";
  $result=mysqli_query($con,$sql) or die("invalid query ".mysqli_error($con));
  while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
    echo $row['name'];
  }
```

now i want to pass this array into javascript array.

```
var images=["$row[0]","$row[1]","$row[2]"];// Is that coreect way to pass php array into js array?
```

if not what is correct way to pass php array to javascript array.

Comment: What makes you think that it's the wrong way? Do you get an error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "username", "password", "database_name");

$query = "SELECT * FROM test;";
$result = $mysqli->query($query);

while($row = $result->fetch_array())
{
    $rows[] = $row;
}
?>

<script>
    var images = [<?=implode(',', $rows);?>];
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM test;";
$result=mysqli_query($con,$sql) or die("invalid query ".mysqli_error($con));
print 'var images=[';
$tmp = array();
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
   $tmp[] = '"'.$row['name'].'"';
}
print implode(',', $tmp);
print '];';
```

Answer (score 0):

this way:

```
var images=["<?php echo $row[0]; ?>", "<?php echo $row[1]; ?>" ... and so on]
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to echo your variables in the javascript, something like:

```
<?php
     $sql="SELECT * FROM test;";
     $result=mysqli_query($con,$sql) or die("invalid query ".mysqli_error($con));
     $counter = 0;
?>

<script>
var images=new Array();
<?php
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
         echo 'images['.$counter.']="'.$row['name'].'";'
         $counter++;
    }
?>
</script>
```

Use a counter to keep track of the position where you want to add the new item.